# Using 'Con' to Create Raster Containing Values in Another Raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, con

I have 2 rasters that I want to combine into 1 raster, so that the 1 raster has values of each of the input rasters.  I think that I want to use a 'Con' statement to do this.  However, I'm having trouble with getting it to give me the output I desire.  My syntax must be incorrect.  Here's what I have:

1) Raster A = raster of interpolated GW surface

2) Raster B = raster of perennial streams

I want to create Raster C and have it be mostly Raster A except where there are perennial streams (water at the surface) and have those areas represented by Raster B.

Comment: Con(IsNull("rasterB"),"rasterA","raster")

Comment: Thanks.  That expression makes all of the cells in the new raster that were from "rasterB" Null.  I want the values from the input "rasterB" to be kept.

Comment: Change it to   "RasterB")